# Extending the database class to get result from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, oop

I have been trying to learn how to use a php class for database operations in an MVC stucture. This is a simple database class which connects to the database.

```
<?php
class Database
{
private $connect;
private $host, $username, $password, $databaseName;

public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $databaseName)
{
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->databaseName = $databaseName;

    $this->connect = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->databaseName);

    if ($this->connect->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error (' . $this->connect->connect_errno . ') '. $this->connect->connect_error);
    }

    return true;
}

public function __destruct()
{
    $this->connect->close();
}
}
```

Instantiate class for connection

```
$db = new Database("localhost", "root", "", "framework");
```

Good till here, it connects and shows and error if there is an error.

Now I have a table 'Members' in the database with three column 1. Id, 2. Name and 3. Email and to display the record in the members table 
I have a Member model file in the model folder (MVC). I tried to extend the Database class like so

```
class Members extends Database {
    public function getMembers() {
        $result = $this->connect->query("SELECT * FROM members");
        return $query->row;
    }
}
```

What I am unable to do (for the past 24 hours) is display the result.

P.S. Will be great even if you can suggest me a tutorial on how to extend database class.

Comment: What is `$query` in `Members`?

Comment: @RC., there are records in the member table and I am trying to get all records to display.

Answer (score 0):

1). A child class cannot directly access its parent *private* properties, so you need *public* modifier method to access its properties from any of its subclasses

```
public function getConnect(){
return $this->connect;
}
public function getUsername(){
return $this->username;
}

public function getPassword(){
return $this->password;
}

public function getDatabaseName(){
return $this->databaseName;
}
```

2).Parent has a constructor to initialize these `$host`, `$username, $password`, `$databaseName` thus the child constructor must refer to its parent *constructor* in his own constructor.

In *inheritance*, we don't instantiate the parent class directly, but initialize its parent properties via the classes extending it (so the `$host`, `$username`, `$password`, `$databaseName` get initialized via subclasses). If you still instantiate the parent class directly, then there's no point anymore of using *inheritance*.

```
class Members extends Database {

  public __construct( $host, $username, $password, $databaseName){
    parent::__construct( $host, $username, $password, $databaseName);
   }
    public function getMembers() {

        $result = $this->getConnect()->query("SELECT * FROM members");
        return $query->row;
    }
}
```